# Self Implementation of map()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to Implement by myself new map() that can get more than one function.

I wrote this code:

```
def map(iterable, *callbacks):
    temporary = []
    callbacksList = list(callbacks)
    for func in callbacksList:
        for item in iterable:
             temporary.append(func(item))
        callbacksList = callbacksList[1:]
        iterable = temporary
        temporary = []
    return iterable
```

The code works fine in this case:

```
c = "hello"
print(map(c,str.upper,ord,chr)) # => ['H','E','L','L','O']
```

but in this case:

```
c = "hello"
print(map(c,str.upper,chr,ord))
```

I got an error "an integer is required (got type str)" - because of chr function that gets str and not int.

I don't understand how can I Adjust my code to work with both cases and be more generic.
Thanks for helpers.

Comment: You can't get the `chr` of a char, so there's no way you can apply these functions in this order. So what would you expect in the second case?

Comment: Unless you have an odd notion of "work" it seems that your code *does* work in both cases since throwing an error is the natural behavior in the second case.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thats the point, I'm asking to understand better if there is a way to do that in Python, I'm kind a new with python.

Comment: A way to do what? Your code already does what John Coleman describes, so what else would you want to do?

Comment: If your `iterable` is a generator this will run into problems, because after the first `for item in iterable` the generator will be empty (or it will run indefinitely, if it is an infinite generator). You probably want to swap your `for` loops.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I just wonder if there is a way to switch places between chr & ord.
John Coleman explained what should I do which is throw an error.

Comment: What he meant is that **Python** throws an error in your second case, as what you ask it to do (get the `chr` of a char) is impossible, not that you should raise an exception yourself somewhere.

Comment: @BenjaminYakobi Python doesn't have the kind of run-time typing you would need to detect that `[ord, chr]` would lead to an error when you try to apply them in that order. It's your responsibility to provide a correctly composable sequence of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your callbacks seem to be applied one after another, why not make this a generator and swap the two `for` loops (so your `iterable` can also be a generator):

```
def map(iterable, *callbacks):
    for item in iterable:
        for f in callbacks:
            item = f(item)
        yield item

list(map("hello", str.upper, ord, chr))
# ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']
```

But just like your code this requires that the output of each function is also a valid input for the following function. If this is not the case, you could ignore all functions that raise an exception:

```
def map2(iterable, *callbacks):
    for item in iterable:
        for f in callbacks:
            try:
                item = f(item)
            except (TypeError, ValueError):  # might want to be more generic than this, depending on your functions
                pass
        yield item

list(map2("hello", str.upper, chr, ord))
# [72, 69, 76, 76, 79]
```

But it really depends on your usecase what the right action is in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You are effectively *composing* your list of callbacks; your call

```
map(c, str.upper, ord, chr)
```

should be equivalent to `map(c, lambda x: chr(ord(str.upper(c))))`. However, your other attempt

```
map(c, str.upper, chr, ord)
```

is equivalent to `map(c, lambda x: ord(chr(str.upper(c)))`, and `ord(chr('x'))` simply isn't defined; `chr` cannot take a string as an argument.

That said, you can simplify your definition by composing the functions first, then using the built-in `map` to apply the composed function.

```
def map(iterable, *callbacks):
    # The identity function i = lambda x: x is the identity for function composition.
    # That is, f(i(x)) == i(f(x)) == f(x)
    f = lambda x: x
    for g in callbacks:
        # The g=g is necessary due to how Python handles name lookups
        f = lambda x, g=g: g(f(x))
    return map(f, iterable)
```

You can also use the `functools.reduce` function to perform the composition.

```
def compose(f,g):
    def _(x):
        return f(g(x))
    return _

def ident(x):
    return x

def map(iterable, *callbacks):
    f = functools.reduce(compose, callbacks, ident)
    return map(f, iterable)
```

---

One important note: this style of programming is not very efficient in Python, due to the extra anonymous functions that get inserted into the call chain and the relatively high cost of a function call.

Comment: Thanks! Got it :))

Comment: `f = lambda x: g(f(x))` won't work. You'd need `f = lambda x, g=g, f=f: g(f(x))` or use an actual `def compose(f, g):` / `def composed(x):` / `return g(f(x))` \ `return composed` in `f = compose(f, g)`